# blur внутри input type="time"

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, время

Я использую `input` с типом time формата `hh:mm`, ставлю фокус на `hh` ввожу часы, нажимаю <kbd>Tab</kbd>, происходит blur на `mm`, вопрос - можно ли сразу подставить `:00`, при этом сохраняя текущее положение фокуса на минутах.

HTML:

```html
<input type="time" value="">
```

CSS:

```css
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Не хотите сразу написать как начальное значеие в `value` например `00:00`?)

Comment: Логика сервиса не предполагает начальных значений, к сожалению, как вариант использование маски maskedinput.
Но проблему это к сожалению не решает, каким всё таки образом ставить нули в минутах и при этом иметь возможность их редактирования в моменте

Comment: Вообще говоря эти встроенные типы time, date и datetime просто отвратительная поддержка (лично для меня как минимум). Во всех компаниях, где я работал, либо библиотеку использовали либо сами писали. Так намного удобнее и гибче получается просто. Можно ставить любые события, получать любые данные и что САМОЕ главно кастомизировать очень легко. Буквально недавно, у нас была задача переделать внешний вид выбора времени. Вместо одной выпдашки, надо было разбить на 2 или 3 в зависимости от условий и вот кастомизация заняло меньше всего времени)))